# android : in application only images from ldpi are showing

Tags: android, hdpi, mdpi

I have my android application. For test i situate 3 different images in folders drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi and drawable-hdpi. They have the same names.
I have read that: 240x320 - ldpi, 320x480 - mdpi, 480x800 - hdpi.
I test my app on my device (HTC Sensation) but only image from drawable-ldpi is showing (and it has bad quality, its fuzzy)
HtC's sensation screen is 540x960. so why image from drawable-hdpi isn't showing and from drawable-ldpi shows ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to check:

- Your drawables have the same name in each of the resource folders
- You have set a fairly recent (since hdpi) api version set in the AndroidManifest.xml

  uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"

Comment: images have the same names. i havent anything about ldpi, mdpi, hdpi in my manifest